Godot Animation tree negative condition
In animation tree I create condition "is_walk" and I can set in the code. But when this condition ends, Walking animation dont return to Idle.
What to write to return Idle if is_walk is false
I tried  !is_walk as condition  is_walk != true as expression but notting seems working .

expressions evaluated as part of class in AnimationTree.
so this produces negative :
self["parameters/conditions/is_walk"] == false

